# Regular Expression for alphabets, numbers and symbols

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a regex for allowing

Alphabets case insensitive   `[a-zA-Z]`
hyphen and underscore    `[-_]`
forward and backward slashes  `[/\\\\]`
numbers `[0-9]`

Hence

```
var regex = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z-_][/\\\\]*$');
regex.test('ABC/90-1_AB');
```

does not work.

Comment: Why didn't you use `[a-zA-Z-_/\\\\]*`? Also, I thought digits shouldn't be allowed?

Comment: You say nothing about matching digits, yet your sample input contains `0` and `9`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current regexp (`/^[a-zA-Z-_][/\\\\]*$/`) is looking for a string that start with a letter, `-` or `_` who are then followed by 0 or more `/` or `\` that end the string.

Put it inside 1 bracket :

```
'^[-_/0-9a-zA-Z\\\\]*$'
```

Comment: Be careful with the hyphen `-` in the middle of your character class!

Comment: @Robin Carefull yes, but it doesn't affect anything here!

Comment: Since hyphens are special characters inside character classes, I think it's best practice to escape them inside (by putting it at the beginning/end `[...-]`). Strictly speaking, since it's right behind another range I don't know if it actually affects things here, but I'd say it's a liability waiting to break stuff at the first change.

Comment: @Robin i actualy like the hyphen here, it look like an hockey stick with a puck. *(yes i'm canadian)*

Comment: You can preserve the fancy look with safety with `[-_/...]`. Writing ASCII art regex is a cause I could get behind!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var regex = new RegExp('[\w\\/-]','i'); // \w matches alphanumeric characters and underscore 
regex.test('ABC/90-1_AB'); // returns true
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6huad/)

Since you aren't willing to have complex `RegExp` why making it difficult, when you can just match your needs with explicitly required symbols